# Running Grails 3 app on Intellij

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I created a default `Grails 3` app using the following commandline:

```
$ grails create-app myapp --profile web --features mongodb,asset-pipeline
```

And then, I opened the project in `IntelliJ IDE 2016.1.`

In the first time, the app started correctly. But, I cannot run it anymore due to the following error:

> Error running Grails: myapp: Grails application is not found.

I tried to reconfigure the running configurations, but my project is not in the list at all, as shown in the following figure:

[IntelliJ Project configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdeDR.png)

Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: From the Project settings -> Modules remove existing module and try adding a new Grails module.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I solved the problem by removing Grails SDK configurations and adding it again. The project is fine now. I just don't know what may have caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To restore sanity to IntelliJ configuration files, the simplest solution on Grails > 3 is to let gradle do the work for you.  First close the project in Intellij, then from a *sh shell cd to your project directory and run 'gradle cleanIdea idea'.  Reopen the project in IntelliJ.   If you were able to start your app with 'grails run-app,' you should now be able to run the app again from within IntelliJ Idea.    This works for me whenever IntelliJ starts displaying the same 'no Grails application' message on opening a project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I solved the problem by removing Grails SDK configurations and adding it again. The project is fine now. I just don't know what may have caused the problem.